# Fetch full list of users who follow me on Tumblr via API

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I'm trying to fetch all of my followers using the PHP API (`$client->getBlogFollowers`). It allows both "limit" and "offset" as parameters, but no matter what I set `limit` to, it always returns exactly 20 results.

Is this a bug, or an enforced upper limit?

I'm trying to cache the results, but to fetch all of it, I will have to call `getBlogFollowers` inside a loop until it retrieves all the data. For an account with 1000+ followers, that would mean looping about 50 times. It would obviously be more efficient if I could stretch the limit to 1000 and get the results in just 1 call, or perhaps 500 and make only 2 calls.

However, when I tried fetching an acount with exactly 2,865 followers, I got a Rate Limit Exceeded error.

> [06-Dec-2015 18:59:41 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Tumblr\API\RequestException: [429]: Rate Limit Exceeded

Is looping the most efficient (or perhaps only?) way to fetch a thousand follower records? Do I need to consider the `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time` of PHP's settings?

Comment: Many web-centric APIs are paginated so you don't tax their server for all the entries when you may only need a handful. Also, with a smaller payload, you are less likely to have the connection drop out partway through each request. If there is a rate limit, a value will often be returned with the payload telling you how long (usually in seconds) you must wait before hitting their server again. Respect that wait time! Otherwise, you will get the error you experienced. I am not familiar with this PHP API, but I am sure you can find a way to get the wait time between hits on the server.